# how to close a sidenav (or bottomnav) programmatically in DreamFace?

Tags: angularjs

When we click away on a sidenav, it closes automatically. I need a behavior such as, when I click on an item in a grid in the sidenav, for the sidenav to close automatically, bringing me to the main card (or a button that does that)

Comment: provide your code it will helpFull to see mistake...

Answer (score 0):

when you define your sidenav, a reference is given. You can use this reference to close the sidenav programmatically, as shown in the following example:

```
$scope.openSideNav = function () {
    var options = {
        width : '400px',
        position : 'left',
        viewName : 'SampleView',
        cardName : 'sampleCard',
        scope : $scope
    }
    $scope.sideNavInstance = dfxSidenav.showView(options);
};

$scope.closeSideNav = function () {
    $scope.sideNavInstance.close();
};
```